# Pulling Null Values On Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a request to pull most recent transaction data for 1000 users, but my query is only pulling about 890 records because some just don't exist in this table. I'd like to be able to pull them even if they don't exist and just leave a null value for the "MostRecentDate"

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
    p.VAL_ID,
    p.VAL_LAST,
    p.VAL_FIRST,
    MAX(a.POSTDATE) AS MostRecentDate
FROM
    TABLE a
JOIN
    TABLE p ON a.ID = p.VAL_ID
WHERE
    p.VAL_ID IN ('insert ID here')

GROUP BY
    p.VAL_ID,
    p.VAL_LAST,
    p.VAL_FIRST;
```

Any and all advice appreciated!

Since someone asked in the comments, editing to add desired results. Note this is pulled from where my code works, but isn't pulling all 1000 records.

[image: Desired Results]

Comment: "...because some just don't exist in this table..." -- Where do they exist?

Comment: Or... add a few rows of sample data and the expected result, to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @TheImpaler they exist in table P, but not necessarily in table A. That's what I need to find out, we're pulling records to see if these users have any transactions in table A

Comment: Maybe use `RIGHT JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`?

Comment: Yep, but as right outer joins can make a query with more tables almost unredable, I wouldn't recommend that. Just never use `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`.  Always arrange your from clause such as to to use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` instead. (Like I did in my answer.)

Comment: Couldn't agree more. RIght joins not only right join the previous table but they silently outer join everything before it, including previously inner-joined tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an outer join it seems:

```
SELECT
    p.VAL_ID,
    p.VAL_LAST,
    p.VAL_FIRST,
    MAX(a.POSTDATE) AS MostRecentDate
FROM p
LEFT OUTER JOIN a ON a.ID = p.VAL_ID
WHERE p.VAL_ID IN ('insert ID here')
GROUP BY
    p.VAL_ID,
    p.VAL_LAST,
    p.VAL_FIRST;
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you so much Thorsten!!